# VUEJS + VUEX State reset everytime dispatch action

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Everytime i dispatch action in vuex it remove my old state of users and add dispatch actions to playlist. I don't know what is problem so sharing screenshot you may understand in image what i am trying to say.

Thing is when application start it works fine with default values but when i add dispatch with some button or event then it remove user state object from vuex but keep playlist with new item in it. I know when dispatch playlist refresh vuex object but how to keep user object same time ?

This is action i added and works fine but i have to do this every time i add something or if other actions then i have to apply same thing.

Any idea i don't have to put user dispatch every time ?

```
addSongToList() {
    playlist.dispatch('addSong', { title: "Beside Me",
                    mp3: "http://dl.jatt.link/lq.jatt.link/cdn8/1a40cff114c5ee39b75dd3813c3f29dd/cdlzv/Ni%20Mainu-(Mr-Jatt.com).mp3",
                });
    store.dispatch('updateUser', this.getUser );
}
```

Thanks

This is my playlist.js store file :

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'

let state = {
    playerList: []
};

let getters = {
    getPlaylist: state => {
        return state.playerList
    }
};

let actions = {
    addSong: ({commit}, song) => {
        commit('ADD_SONG_TO_PLAYLIST', song)
    }
};

let mutations = {
    ADD_SONG_TO_PLAYLIST(state, song) {
        state.playerList.push(song)
    }
};

let playlist = new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions,
});

global.playlist = playlist;

export default playlist
```

This is user.js

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import playlist from './playlist'

let state = {
    user: {}
};

let getters = {
    getUser: state => {
        return state.user
    }
};

let actions = {
    updateUser: ({commit}, user) => {
        commit('ADD_USER', user)
    },
    deleteUser: ({commit}) => {
        commit('DELETE_USER')
    }
};

let mutations = {
    ADD_USER(state, user) {
        state.user = user
    },
    DELETE_USER(state) {
        state.user = null
    }
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    modules: {
        playlist
    },
    mutations,
})
```

[image]

Comment: In the official documentation, modules are defined as simple objects, not entire stores. Try replacing `let playlist = new Vuex.Store({...});` with just `let playlist = {...}` and report back if that solves the problem.